# Braintree dropin UI - Access token needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway

Tags: php, symfony, braintree

Symfony 4 app with Braintree JS drop-in UI

I have created a service called Braintree to start testing.

```
namespace App\Services;

use Braintree\ClientToken;


class Braintree
{

    // environment variables:
    const ENVIRONMENT = 'BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT';
    const MERCHANT_ID = 'BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID';
    const PUBLIC_KEY = 'BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY';
    const PRIVATE_KEY = 'BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY';

    /** @var \Braintree_Gateway */
    private $gateway;

    function __construct() {
        $gateway = new \Braintree_Gateway([
            'environment' => getenv(self::ENVIRONMENT),
            'merchantId' => getenv(self::MERCHANT_ID),
            'publicKey' => getenv(self::PUBLIC_KEY),
            'privateKey' => getenv(self::PRIVATE_KEY)
        ]);
    }

public function generate() {
    return ClientToken::generate();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway).
```

The BT config has been properly entered into the .env file. Why is it not setting the MERCHANT_ID?

Edit:

Add config

```
Braintree_Gateway:
    class: Braintree_Gateway
    arguments:
        -
          'environment': '%env(BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT)%'
          'merchantId': '%env(BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID)%'
          'publicKey': '%env(BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
          'privateKey': '%env(BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY)%'
```

Edit 2:

The stack trace:

```
Braintree\Exception\
Configuration
in vendor\braintree\braintree_php\lib\Braintree\Configuration.php (line 261)
    public function assertHasAccessTokenOrKeys()    {        if (empty($this->_accessToken)) {            if (empty($this->_merchantId)) {                throw new Exception\Configuration('Braintree\\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\\Gateway).');            } else if (empty($this->_environment)) {                throw new Exception\Configuration('Braintree\\Configuration::environment needs to be set.');            } else if (empty($this->_publicKey)) {                throw new Exception\Configuration('Braintree\\Configuration::publicKey needs to be set.');            } else if (empty($this->_privateKey)) {
Configuration->assertHasAccessTokenOrKeys()
in vendor\braintree\braintree_php\lib\Braintree\ClientTokenGateway.php (line 34)
ClientTokenGateway->__construct(object(Gateway))
in vendor\braintree\braintree_php\lib\Braintree\Gateway.php (line 59)
Gateway->clientToken()
in vendor\braintree\braintree_php\lib\Braintree\ClientToken.php (line 18)
ClientToken::generate()
in src\Services\Braintree.php (line 25)
Braintree->generate()
in src\Controller\ProfileController.php (line 50)
ProfileController->booking_new(object(EntityManager), object(Request), object(Braintree))
in vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php (line 149)
```

**Edit 3:**

```
namespace App\Services;

use Braintree_Gateway;

class Braintree extends Braintree_Gateway
{

    //Configure Braintree Environment
    public function __construct(Braintree_Gateway $gateway)
    {
        $this->$gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
            'environment' => 'sandbox',
            'merchantId' => 'n5z3tjxh8zd6272k',
            'publicKey' => 'v4rjdzqk3gykw4kv',
            'privateKey' => '4ab8b962e81ee8c43bf6fa837cecfb97'
        ]);
    }

    //Generate a client token
    public function generate() {
        return $clientToken = $this->clientToken()->generate();
    }

}
```

Error is now:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Braintree\Gateway could not be converted to string
```

Am I getting closer to generating the client token??

Answer (score 1):

The `.env`-file does not actually populate the system environment. Instead it works as a fallback when the environment is not set. Your call to `getenv()` only takes into account the system environment. For your file to take effect you have to use the Service container.

```
#config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    #... all the existing services

    Braintree_Gateway:
        class: Braintree_Gateway
        arguments:
            -
              'environment': '%env(BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT)%'
              'merchantId': '%env(BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID)%'
              'publicKey': '%env(BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
              'privateKey': '%env(BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY)%'
```

The special parameter `%env()%` will check your system environment for the variable first and if that is not set it will go through the `.env` files to see if there is a fallback defined. You can also read up on this in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#environment-variables

This will give the service `Braintree_Gateway`, that you built manually inside your service. Just like with any other service you can inject it into your service instead and autowiring will pass in an already generated Braintree Gateway:

```
namespace App\Services;

use Braintree\ClientToken;

class Braintree
{
    private $gateway;

    public function __construct(\Braintree_Gateway $gateway)
    {
        $this->gateway = $gateway;
    }

    # ... methods using the gateway
}
```

Comment: The definition for "Braintree_Gateway" has no class attribute, and appears to reference a class or interface in the global namespace. Leaving out the "class" attribute is only allowed for namespaced classes. Please specify the class attribute explicitly to get rid of this error... was error I got when I tried this.

Comment: Furthermore I don't understand ... if it doesn't need the values that are in my .env file, where else would it get the actual values from? thanks

Comment: I updated the example. Just add the `class:` property in your services.yaml to fix the error. `getenv()` reads it from the System Environment. On a Linux server that means you export a variable, e.g. using the CLI: `export BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT=my_braintree_environment`. The Wikipedia page for [Environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) will give you a pretty good overview of what they are. The `.env` file is just a means to share variables between systems or provide a template which varibles to set between systems.

Comment: Thanks for help. Sorry but now I am back to the original error about MerchantID not set. I definitely have used your updates, and have a correct sandbox MerchantID in the .env file. Do not get why it is not working.

Comment: I just hard coded 'merchantId': 'XXXXXXXXXX' and still same error. Shouldn't there be more stuff in the constructor for Braintree.php?

Comment: No, your Braintree-class only needs the gateway. Actually from what you posted it doesn't even need the gateway, as the variable is never used. ;) The `Braintree_Gateway` class requires all your parameters inside an array. That is why my definition has one argument (as seen by the `-`) containing of an array with named keys and the variables from the `.env` file. What is the error that you still get? The one regarding class? Did you update your `config/services.yaml` and if so could you add the current version to your question, please?

Comment: Have added config with edit. No I'm getting the original error about Merchant ID not set.

Comment: Could you show the complete error message (including the stacktrace)? Are you sure it's caused by your `Braintree`-class or maybe the wrongly configured Gateway was used somewhere else? Also, which `.env`-file did you put the credentials in? Are you using the new `.env`-style with a `.env.local` or the old one (do you also have a `.env.dist` file?)?

Comment: Have added stack trace. Credentials are in .env file (the regular type). No I don't have a .env.dist file since starting project. Config worked before I tried this change to the new way of authenticating, so probably no problem with .env file.

Comment: You are not using the local variable from the constructor anywhere. Could it be that you create a new `$gateway` somewhere else and that is causing the issue? Please make sure to differentiate between `$gateway` (local scope) and `$this->gateway` (class scope). Looking at your initial code `$gateway` in the constructor will not be available in any other method. If you instead use `$this->gateway = new Braintree_Gateway(...)` then all other methods (inside this class) can access it, once it was created.

Comment: Ok, have added edit 3 based on your advice, brings new error, see above under edit 3.

Comment: Could it be that `$this->clientToken()->generate();` is the cause of the error? From what I can gather `clientToken()` is a method on the gateway not your Braintree-class. Have you tried `return $this->gateway->clientToken()->generate();` instead?

Comment: Needed to use Braintree\Gateeway class, declare a private $gateway variable,, type hint Gateway $gateway into the constructor, then use $this->gateway = $gateway, then add some config to services.yaml